# Best development environment using Spring MVC, JRebel for Java web app?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, jrebel

I looking for the current best combination of tools for developing a Java web app using Spring MVC (and Spring) and JRebel. Which IDE (which version, which plugins?), which other build tools (maven, gradle?)? Tomcat/Jetty? Embedded? How to fit them together so that the development process becomes quick and painless.

Has anybody got some tried and tested combinations that work really well? Any you would avoid?

I'm developing on Windows 7, using Java 7, looking to use latest production releases of libraries/frameworks.

Comment: Questions like this are viewed as non-constructive because they are a matter of opinion; i.e. it is next to impossible to say *objectively* what is "best".  (And besides, a typical Answer will tend to get out of date, and hence "less correct" over time.)

Comment: Yes but the criteria is quite narrow. Java Web App, Spring MVC, JRebel  etc. There is scope for opinion but it's limited.

Comment: Have you checked the use of [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/#headline) ?

Comment: Yes, there is a JRebel Spring plugin which I think is needed if you're going to get the advantages of using JRebel with Spring MVC. So I guess I'm looking for anybody using this in the real world and details of their environment setup/tools/development process etc. Thanks.

Comment: I don;t know why people bother  with jrebel, I have hot deploy working like a dream (everything, js, jsp, java), the only thing it can't do is changes to method signatures ... so maybe once a day I might need to do an actual redeploy, that takes 10 secs. Intellij rocks btw http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/21987/how-is-intellij-better-than-eclipse/168332#168332

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I see, what you really want to know is, if you're using JRebel with Eclipse, would you be able to see the changes instantly. So if I'm right about that, then JRebel will do the job you want.

> With JRebel you can see all changes to Java code instantly in the browser. Save and
>   refresh! The same is true for your other project files.

I've used it and it deploys your java file as soon as you save it, without even popping up some window which happens when you use build automatically in eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I guess my question was not really clear enough. But I'm interested specifically in JRebel used on a Spring MVC (+Spring) web app. As I understand it it requires a separate plugin (JRebel Spring plugin). So I'm interested in people who use this and their dev setup. Thanks.

Comment: The plugin is inbuilt with JRebel, you don't need to buy that explicitly. I've the same configuration as yours and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks, great. Can I ask which version of Eclipse you use, and which Eclipse plugins you have (excluding JRebel)?. Do you run an embedded Tomcat - and are able to leave that running, making changes to Java code (Spring beans etc), JSP etc and have all changes propagate instantly. Do you need to restart every now and again or can you run it all day?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Juno with Jboss which has embedded Tomcat and yes I can leave the server running, making changes to any file in the code. And I don't need to restart it now and then, just once :)

Comment: Sounds great! Is that 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers' rather than any other of the versions. You don't have the WTP plugin as well for example? Is JBoss separate from Eclipse - do you configure your 'app server runtime' when installing the JRebel plugin? thanks.

Comment: Yes, if I'm using same configuration as yours, it must be a Java EE IDE only. And I don't have WTP plugin and configuring JRebel for Jboss is simple, I'm using it outside only, just check out JRebel website for configuring your application.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I m using following :
1.IDE-eclipse juno with latest version.
2.Server-jboss-5.1.0.GA 
3.Framework-Spring MVC architecture.
4.front End-JSF
I think this is the good one configuration for any web application project

Comment: I was more interested in the JRebel component, being able to makes changes to a running web application during the development process. Do you have this? Does it work well?

Comment: Yes, I have used it with eclipse, and its working perfectly for me.

Comment: Spring MVC and JSF? I'm was asking only in reference to Spring MVC.

Comment: Can you make changes to Spring beans and Spring Controllers and see those changes instantly applied to a running web app instance?

Comment: If you're considering the development environment w.r.t the support it may provide you in deployment, there are no issues with Eclipse + JRebel. Now considering SpringMVC I really don't understand what difference it makes to you if you use eclipse or some other IDE.

Comment: In JRebel we can see those changes instantly applied to a running web app instance.

Comment: Um.. that's what I'd like to avoid if possible :)

Comment: You said 'no' then changed your answer, so now I don't know whether your set up allows Spring beans/controller instance updates or not. Maybe this is too open ended discussion. Thanks anyway.